# react-native at different modules ambiguous or not recognized

Tags: node.js, react-native, dependencies, node-modules, packager

I've two different modules that have dependencies that use react-native and one of them have react-native on node_modules. 
If i run project with only one react-native, the dependencies from the other module not recognize react-native, but if install react-native on all of them, gives an error that react-native is ambiguous because is duplicated.

Is any way to prevent duplicated modules on package loader or one other solution for this?

Thanks!